# REST APIs to fetch statistic api usage data from API Connect

Tags: apiconnect

This may look a dumb question to you. However, I am looking for a way to fetch API Connect internal data i.e. number of invocations of APIs exposed via API Connect , by which client etc. I know, there are individual dashboard/chart within API Connect. But, I want to build a explicit tool to monitor the same leveraging API Connect data.

is it at all possible ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

See the KC at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMNED_5.0.0/com.ibm.apic.apionprem.doc/rapim_analytics_apieventrecordfields.html which will explain how to get the info you want.

Procedure
To obtain analytics data for a Catalog and API provider organization, issue the following call:

GET /v1/orgs/{orgId}/environments/{envId}/events

where

```
{orgId} is either the URL path segment or the ID of the API provider organization.
{envId} is either the URL path segment or the ID of the Catalog.
```

The following example shows a call that is issued from a browser and then shows all the event fields in the corresponding response. The call is issued to return two analytics events (limit=2), and includes a next parameter for requesting further events.

https://api-manager-server.company.com/v1/orgs/macs-shack/environments/sb/events?next&limit=2

Comment: @Dhrubo Did this help solve your question? If so please mark this question as answered